# Check if element is x pixels away from being visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this function to check if an element is visible on the screen:

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem){
  var $elem = $(elem);
  var $window = $(window);

  var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();

  var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

  return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

How can this be modified so that it will return `true` if an element is x pixels (e.g. 500 px) away from being visible on screen? (With the element being below the screen).

Comment: What you are asking seems to be the opposite of the entire point of the `isScrolledIntoView` function. Would it matter if the image is above, below, right, or left of the screen? Also are you actually having an input `x`, where the element must be exactly `x` away, or would it be `x` or less away?

Comment: The element should be below the screen. It should be exactly `x` away (if JS is able to 'capture' it in time while the user is scrolling? Or might it skip it like 501 -> 499 px?). For clarification this is for an infinite scroll system like FB does (loading more content before they reach the bottom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this function works the way you want it to, just add to docViewBottom

```
var x = 500; // or whatever buffer you find works best     
var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height() + x;
```